# Bing - how to index more than 10 URLs per day?

Tags: seo, bing

I've started working with Bing and it appears it only allows 10 URLs to be indexed per day, in a newline delimited format, in a Web form, once logged in to an account.

I'm thinking of using a Google sitemap.xml file as a starting point and cron to periodically submit all the urls over time, but it seems like there has to be a better way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Bing supports sitemap files](https://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-US/bing/hh204487%28d=lightweight%29.aspx), so you might not need to manually submit the URLs.

Comment: Thanks Kurt; I actually submitted a sitemap.xml file several days ago yet nothing is indexed.  There are messages stating information will appear in 3 days, but nothing has been indexed yet.  Hopefully submitting urls for indexing will result in quicker initial indexing (It's clear they only allow 10 per day though): https://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/gg132935(d=lightweight).aspx